# Forwarding tcp to d-bus via socat failed

Tags: d-bus, freedesktop

I'm trying to build a tcp proxy to my local session dbus daemon. I did

```
 socat TCP-LISTEN:55556,reuseaddr,fork,range=127.0.0.1/32 ABSTRACT-CONNECT:/run/user/1000/bus
```

However, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=127.0.0.1,port=55556 notify-send hello` gives this error

```
2018/12/31 03:11:56 socat[4316] E connect(5, AF=1 "\0/run/user/1000/bus", 21): Connection refused
2018/12/31 03:11:56 socat[4317] E connect(5, AF=1 "\0/run/user/1000/bus", 21): Connection refused
```

How can I fix that? I don't care about security issues at all since this is a offline box.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify with `ss -xnl` that the unix socket is displayed beginning with `@` to make it an abstract socket. I'm betting there's no such `@`. I have two systems running quite different versions. One is listening with abstract sockets with random entries like `@/tmp/dbus-QVAhTtSPNB` the other is listening with unix (*non* abstract) sockets with `/run/user/1000/bus`.

The correct command is probably:

```
 socat TCP-LISTEN:55556,reuseaddr,fork,range=127.0.0.1/32 UNIX-CONNECT:/run/user/1000/bus
```

Comment: After switching to `UNIX-CONNECT`, the dbus request is silently dropped as if there isn't a dbus service available.

Comment: @Amos Running your setup with my solution,  but using `dbus-monitor` instead of `notify-send hello` gets me a whole dump of information from to dbus